# How to invoke the increment and decrement Normal-mode commands in Vimscript?

Tags: vim

I’m trying to create a Vimscript function that randomly increments ro decrements the number under the cursor, so I can call it from a macro. So far, I’ve got this:

```
function! RandomIncDec() 
    python import random
    python vim.command("let l:random = " + str(random.randint(-15, 15)))
    if l:random > 0
        exec ':normal ' . l:random . '<C-a>'
    elseif l:random < 0
        exec ':normal ' . abs(l:random) . '<C-x>'
    endif
endfunction

command! RandIncDec :call RandomIncDec()
```

The problem I’m having is that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> keys don’t seem to work from Vimscript this way.

I’ve also tried using the `feedkeys()` function to try and emulate the keypresses as well, but that doesn’t seem to do the trick either. I could probably do this by calling the underlying functions that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> are mapped to, but as they are core, I can’t find out what they are from `:map`.

What is the correct way to do this from Vimscript?

Comment: By the way, haven't you forgot dot operator between number and `<C-a>`/`<C-x>`?

Comment: You're right, had to make this change as well. Edited my question to include this update in case anyone else is trying to do the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try typing `<C-a>` and `<C-x>` as
[<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>] and [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>],
respectively.
After doing so, those `exec` lines should look like so:

```
exec ':normal ' . l:random . '^A'
exec ':normal ' . abs(l:random) . '^X'
```

where `^A` and `^X` are single characters.

Another (and probably nicer) way is to use double-quote string
expansion (see `:help expr-quote`):

```
exec ':normal ' . l:random . "\<C-A>"
exec ':normal ' . abs(l:random) . "\<C-X>"
```

Comment: Brilliant, didn't know about Ctrl+V in insert mode. This has done the trick nicely :-) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Instead of inserting "hard" control characters into your script file, you can instead use double quoted strings and backslash the < character, for example: exec ':normal ' . l:random . "\<C-a>"

Comment: @Heptite: Thanks for the suggestion!  Backslash expansion is better than hard-coded non-printable characters.

Comment: Ahh, I tried \<C-a> in single quotes and it didn't work, didn't realise the distinction between single and double quotes here. More knowledge! Thanks Heptite.

Comment: The relevant vim doc on escaping special keys are `:h expr-quote`.

Comment: @jdhao: Yes, and that help section is already referenced in the answer (right before the second code block).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't test following on unix.

```
function! s:srand()
  if has('win32') || has('win64')
    call libcallnr("msvcrt.dll", "srand", localtime())
  else
    call libcallnr("libc.so", "srand", localtime())
  endif
endfunction

function! s:rand()
  if has('win32') || has('win64')
    return libcallnr("msvcrt.dll", "rand", -1)
  else
    return libcallnr("libc.so", "rand", -1)
  endif
endfunction

call s:srand()

function! s:RandomInc()
  let r = s:rand()%3 + 1
  exe "normal! ".r."\<c-a>"
endfunction

function! s:RandomDec()
  let r = s:rand()%3 + 1
  exe "normal! ".r."\<c-x>"
endfunction

nmap <c-a> :call <SID>RandomInc()<cr>
nmap <c-x> :call <SID>RandomDec()<cr>
```